# 2sxc DNN objects on Hybrid templates

Tags: 2sxc, dnn9

Having just the `@inherits Custom.Hybrid.Razor12` at the top of the template breaks it when using DNN objects.

> *... The type or namespace name 'Portal' does not exist in the namespace 'Dnn' (are you missing an assembly reference?)...*

Adding `@inherits ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.RazorComponent` fixes it, everything displays properly.

**My question is do I need both or just the latter?** Everything seems to work fine if I remove `@inherits Custom.Hybrid.Razor12`, but perhaps there's a better way to have the DNN objects without breaking the template. Or it may be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I think Daniel (iJungleBoy) already answered this in the comments here.
[Correct way to get access to Dnn Stuff while using Modern 2sxc Hybrid Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353751/correct-way-to-get-access-to-dnn-stuff-while-using-modern-2sxc-hybrid-views)

"to get the Dnn object you must use the base class Custom.Dnn.Razor12 - it's only difference is the Dnn object. That cannot work on Hybrid, because Oqtane won't have a Dnn object - otherwise it's the same as Custom.Hybrid.Razor12"